# Is it safe to power a 140mA laptop cooler pad off a USB 3.0 port?

Tags: laptop, usb, power, cooling, usb-3

I have acquired a laptop cooler pad that connects to a USB port for power.

The problem is it draws 140mA. That's more than a dumb device is allowed to draw off USB 2.0 (max is 100mA unless the device asks for more – I doubt this cooler does that).

So I'm thinking of using a USB 3.0 port, but I need someone to definitively confirm that a dumb device drawing 140mA off USB 3.0 is OK.

Also, while we're at it, are there any other risks/issues with using gimmicky things like fans off a USB port? I really don't want to inadvertently damage a USB controller or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**K7AAY** pointed me [to the USB specs (in this ZIP archive)](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_31_121314.zip) and I'm grateful for that.

Quoting from 9.2.5.1:

> Devices shall limit the power they consume from V BUS to one unit load
>   or less until configured. When operating at Gen X speed, 150 mA equals
>   one unit load.

Gen X means SuperSpeed or SuperSpeedPlus (USB 3.0 or 3.1).

So that clears things up. A dumb device isn't going to configure anything so, if it is to behave within spec, it must draw no more than 150mA.

My laptop cooler draws 140mA which is just within the USB 3.0 spec.